# Crystal Report Not Generating Correct Output

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports-2010

I have Designed Crystal Report like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKRSR.png

But I m getting this output

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k7uB.png

can someone suggest me why correct output was not generating

I m using Visual Studio 2010 and CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0

Thanks